# Rounding the given number

Tags: excel, rounding

I know we can get result in rounding off the number. My question is, how we can tell Excel to use the given number by rounding it off.
e.g

```
40.50 x 15 = 607.50
```

I want Excel to take given number `40.50` as `41`, i.e.

```
41 x 15 = 615.00
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/round-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Round()` function. The 'ROUND' function rounds a number to a specified number of digits. You can see the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/round-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c) here.

For example:

```
=ROUND(40.5,0)*15
```

If you want to use cell reference the use like

```
=ROUND(A1,0)*B1
```

The "0" in the given form is the `num_digits` argument: the number of digits after the decimal points to which you want to round the number argument.

[image]